# How to convert Top-and-Bottom 3d video to side-by-side 3d video with FFmpeg

Tags: 3d, ffmpeg

I have a top-and-bottom 3d video, and i want to look at it with Gear VR, but Gear VR only support side-by-side video, so i need to convert it to side-by-side, while i don't know how to use ffmpeg to achieve it,does anyone knows ? thanks very much.

Answer (score 12):

See [stereo3d](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#stereo3d) filter documentation:

`ffmpeg -i top-and-bottom.mov -vf stereo3d=abl:sbsl -c:a copy side-by-side.mov`

Answer (score 2):

It works, but... the movie I had was 1920x1080 over/under, and this command spliced the two pictures and put them side by side, creating a 3840x540 movie which doesn't play correctly on my system.
This did a better job for me:

```
ffmpeg -i ou.mkv -vf "stereo3d=abl:sbsl,scale=1920x1080" -aspect 16:9 -c:a copy sbs.mkv
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not working for me the image get stretched, and any experiments with aspect or resolution gives me unpredictable result, the image get cropped top bottom

Comment: no scale no aspect gives me
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 3840x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 64:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)

but if try to stretch window get same proportion and actual picture get stretched

Answer (score 2):

If you have Side-by-Side in a 1920x1080-Movie and want to change the sides, then take this:

```
ffmpeg -i Movie_sbs_rl.mkv -vf stereo3d=sbs2r:sbs2l -c:a copy Movie_sbs_lr.mkv
```

PS: I know this is an old treat, but the first answer helped me and here is my solution for the second problem. Do a `ffmpeg -h full >help.txt` and read the file, there you find at `stereo3d` all formats possible for 3D.